# Printing using a non-mono font and using texttopdf

Tags: printing, fonts, pdf, mono, cups-lpd

Well, what's in this [article](https://wiki.debian.org/CUPSTextToPdfFilter?highlight=%28CategoryPrinter%29) it is written about changing the standard printing font to some other, but for some reason only mono font. And the question arises whether it is possible to do it with a non-mono font, and if yes, how?